# How does GTM dataLayer data go from a browser to the GTM console?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

Perhaps a very obvious question, so please indulge me - how and when do the contents of the dataLayer on a users' browser make it to the users' GTM console / portal?

Having looked at the network requests, I can't see any traffic that might correspond to this data yet my implementation is working. I've looked at the GTM docs and can't verify it either. So how do all the events we're tracking in the dataLayer arrive in GTM console / portal?

*to be clear, the events from my GTM implementation are being received in GTM console, but I just don't know how it works?*

I tried looking in the Chrome network inspector and didn't see traffic transferring the dataLayer (which is how I anticipated it worked)

Any insight would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

In short: GTM's Web container doesn't have a need to communicate with its servers after the initial load of the container. All logic is downloaded within it and all decisioning is happening locally.

Ok, you're asking this question because you have some assumptions that are not true. These are common GTM beginner misconceptions. I just took a quick look at GTM's documentation and yes, it looks like it makes no effort to explain it better, but that's just pretty much the way any TMS works.

There's no such a thing as GTM portal or GTM console if we're talking about data destinations. There is a GTM web interface with the UI to edit the content of the library, but it doesn't receive traffic from the site. All it does is builds the library depending on how its UI been used to configure it. There's an api to manage it programmatically, but that doesn't

If we're talking about Web-GTM, then it is just a JS bundle/library that you load onto your page and it sends hits from it directly to tracking endpoints, none of which is GTM.

Now, how it works with the DL.

When you load the script of your GTM's container onto your page, one of the first things it does is overriding the dataLayer.push() method to add a listener to it to be able to immediately react to anything new that's pushed into it. All the trigger/tag/variable logic is in your page within the GTM container, so no need to post-process the data and send DL values elsewhere.

That's why GTM needs things like unsafe-eval for CJS variables and unsafe-inline for templates and CHTML tags.